# how to pass value from publisher to subscriber using header in WSO2ESB

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I want to pass a value from WSO2 publisher to Subscriber, where as If the value is hardcoded its working but if trying make it dynamically I'm facing some issues.

Publisher Code:
        MainTopic$ctx:retryCountTemp

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Publisher Code: 
<header name="retryCountTemp" scope="transport" value="3"/>    <kafkaTransport.publishMessages>    <topic>MainTopic</topic>    <MainTopic.retryCount>{$ctx:retryCountTemp}</MainTopic.retryCount>    </kafkaTransport.publishMessages>

Subscriber Code:<log level="custom">     <property expression="get-property('MainTopic.retryCount')"
            name="test1234567" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>   </log>
Output: $ctx:retryCountTemp